# How to read the key value pair from yaml file if the key is email id?

Tags: yaml, yq

Yaml File name: abc.yaml

abc.yaml content

```
abc@in.xyz.com: 12345
xyz@in.xxx.com: 23456
```

I have tried with `yq read abc.yaml abc@in.xyz.com` the output is empty.

Comment: If the answer provided helps, you should consider upvoting (^) and accepting (tick-mark) next to the answer. See SO guidelines for [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Under mikefarah/yq 3.x, to access [path names with special characters](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/v/v3.x/usage/path-expressions#special-characters), you quote them with `"`, so it will be

```
yq read abc.yaml '"abc@in.xyz.com"'
```

---

If you are using v3.x in production or build pipelines you should know that it is no longer supported by the author and should consider upgrading to v4.x, as it supports much more features. See notes on [Upgrading from V3](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/upgrading-from-v3)

On latest version `yq version 4.4.1`, you could just do

```
yq e '."abc@in.xyz.com"' abc.yaml
```